# Shall We Provisionally Open Our Scope to Dancing-focused Question?

Tags: discussion, scope

Following a suggestion that was a response to [my prior meta question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/music-and-dance-fans), I am proposing that **we provisionally open our scope to dance questions** as a kind of trial towards officially changing our name and scope.  Please vote on one of the yes or no answers below (or suggest an alternate answer), we'll take this as our direction going forward.

EDIT: Given that so few people have voted one way or another, I'm taking it that most people don't care either way.  So I'm going to start writing dance-only questions with references back to this discussion.  If we get more votes, we can change the decision if necessary.

Comment: Great, all tied up at one vote each.... :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we should provisionally allow dance (dancing) questions, even ones without a music focus.

By "dance" questions, this means "dance fan" questions, which is to say questions by or for people who are fans of dancing, not necessarily practitioners.  That includes questions about dancers and about specific dances, but probably not dance technique questions.

NOTE: This is not a vote for changing our official name and scope, it is a vote for allowing the trial inclusion of dance.

Answer (score 3):

No, we should remain solely focused on music questions, and continue to close any dance questions as off-topic.